# jQuery waypoint for loop: fade line of divs out

Tags: jquery, for-loop, fadeto

I have 10 lines of divs that stack on top of each other and am trying to fade a line of divs every time they reach a certain .waypoint on my page. This is the jQuery code I have, but instead of causing each line of div to fade out when it reaches 40% from the top of the page, it simply causes the 9th line of the div to fade and only the 9th line. How do I get it so that every div/line fades when it reaches the .waypoint 40%?

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    $('.infinite-container' + i).waypoint(function () {
            $('.infinite-container' + i).fadeTo('slowly', 0);
    }, {offset: '40%'});
}
```

My html looks like this (goes up to infinite-container10):

```
<div class="infinite-container1">
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
    <div class="infinite-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` points to the current element:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    $('.infinite-container' + i).waypoint(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo('slowly', 0);
    }, {offset: '40%'});
}
```

If all of your elements share the same class you don't need a loop at all:

```
    $('.infinite-container').waypoint(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo('slowly', 0);
    }, {offset: '40%'});
```

Take a look at the example of the jQuery waypoint documentation:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/examples/dial-controls/

```
$('.dial li').waypoint( function(direction) {
  var $active = $(this);
  var property, value;
  // ...
});
```

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/examples/scroll-analytics/

```
$('.ad-unit').waypoint(function() {
  recordAdEvent($(this).data('analyticsid'));
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gwFg/)</kbd>

Comment: If I didn't want to write out all the divs in the html, would it make sense to do a loop to .append more divs?

Comment: Like such:     for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++){
        $('.infinite-container' + i).waypoint(function(){
            $('.infinite-container' + i).append('<div class="infinite-item"></div>');
        }, {offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
    }